# How to update value of a textbox when the value of another textbox changes.

Tags: javascript

I have a problem. I have a user control which contains multiple textboxes. When I update a value in one textbox it should calculate value and fill the value in another textbox automatically. I am writing Javascript code in Usercontrol.

When I change the value in the textbox, I am trying to get elementIDs of other textboxes.It shows me an error. It looks to me the elements are not present or they are somewhere else.

Can anyone give me a simple example?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to post your code before we know what's wrong with your current code.

Comment: try giving the user control ID mode to static for further help post the code so that we have a better understanding

Answer (score -1):

if you use jQuery...

```
var ids = [];
$('input[type=text]').each(function() {
    ids.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

ids is now an array of all the ids of the inputs that have the type of text

Comment: How does it answer the question?